# Spark cluster CI pipeline fails to build

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I work on a CI pipeline to build a spark cluster. Anytime I run it locally with command `docker-compose build && compose up -d`, the containers and image are up. On a remote environment, the following log text appears.

```
> Run docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
Creating network "sparkles_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "hadoop-distributed-file-system" with local driver
Pulling jupyterlab (jupyterlab:3.0.0-spark-3.0.0)...
The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

pull access denied for jupyterlab, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
Continue with the new image? [yN]
```

My questions are: To build containers remotely:

1. is login necessary?
2. the pipeline login-build-up seems legit?
3. why is it trying to pull instead of build from remotely local environment?

Would you mind helping me? The repository is available here: https://github.com/trouchet/sparkles/tree/master